# JWplayer suddenly not working - says Java not installed, but it IS (playback issue)

Tags: java, video, jwplayer, playback

I was using openjdk 7, then all of a sudden I wasn't able to stream a video with JWplayer. I tried setting $PATH in Ubuntu 14.04 among lots of other things until I just gave up and purged openjdk completely. I installed Oracle 8, and I still get the same issue.

```
$ java -version
java version "1.8.0_20"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_20-b26)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.20-b23, mixed mode)
```

The videos just say that Java is not installed, to install it and restart my browser, etc.

This is extremely frustrating. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you manage to make it work? can you share the code? please

Answer (score 1):

JW Player does not make any use of Java at all. It is a script written in Javascript, which is simply part of your browser.

Comment: Then why is it complaining about Java not being installed?

Comment: I have no idea. It would be like JW Player saying that you need to have MS Excel installed, or Minecraft. JW Player does not have a single line of Java in it. It is not a Java application, nor does it use Java applets. Please give us a link to a site that displays this bizarre behavior.

Comment: The player isn't something that can be installed on a machine, it resides on a web server. It's a tool for webmasters for video publishing.